# Enthalpy and Bond Energy Sign Convention

Tags: bond, energy, enthalpy, heat, free-energy

I read that a negative enthalpy of formation means an exothermic reaction. Does that mean this reaction is true? The enthalpy of formation for $\ce{H_2O}$ is -285.8 kJ/mol.

$$\ce{2H2(g) + O2(g) -> 2H2O(l) + 285.8*2 kJ}$$

What about the enthalpy of reaction though? Is it also negative for exothermic reactions, like the one above? I think it's calculated with: $\Delta H$(Rxn) = Sum of Heat of Formation of Products – Sum of Heat of Formation of Products.

What about bond enthalpy (bond energy)? I know the calculation is different:
$\Delta H$(bond energy) = Sum of Bond Energy of **reactants** – Sum of Bond Energy of **products**, so are **positive** bond enthalpies exothermic (like in the example above)?

Finally, for Gibbs free energy, $\Delta G=\Delta H-T \Delta S$, is enthalpy in the equation for enthalpy of reaction since it's the change in enthalpy?

Comment: Enthalpy of product formation = enthalpy of reaction (if normalized to the same amount), if reactants are elements in their standard state, as the enthalpy of formation of the latter is conventionally zero.

Comment: When writing $\ce{2H2(g) + O2(g) => 2H2O(l) + 285.8⋅2 kJ}$, the sign plus (+) before $285.8$ shows that the reaction is exothermic, and that this amount of heat is getting out of the system. But it also implies that $\ce{\Delta H_{reaction}}$ is negative, and equal to  $- 285.8·2$ kJ !